# My Confusion about terminology in FTA

Tags: polynomials, roots

I read the following text on [This Page](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MTH_165_College_Algebra_MTH_175_Precalculus/03%3A_Polynomial_and_Rational_Functions/3.06%3A_Zeros_of_Polynomial_Functions):

> Does every polynomial have at least one **imaginary zero**?
>
> No. Real numbers are a subset of complex numbers, but not the other
> way around. A complex number is not necessarily imaginary. Real
> numbers are also complex numbers.

Now, [FTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) states that:

> every non-constant single-variable polynomial with complex
> coefficients **has at least one complex root.** This includes
> polynomials with real coefficients, since every real number is a
> complex number with its imaginary part equal to zero.

my understanding is that, unless "Complex Root" means something different than "Imaginary Zero", the former page statement is wrong. Please clarify the situation. Thanks.

Edit: After reading the good comments below, I came across this diagram which helps:
[Diagram-Classifying Numbers](https://flexbooks.ck12.org/cbook/ck-12-interactive-algebra-2/section/3.8/related/lesson/defining-complex-numbers-alg-ii/)

Comment: The answer is right there on "This Page": a complex number is not necessarily imaginary.  Why don't you believe it?

Comment: Perhaps your confusion comes from the fact that people sometimes say "complex roots" when they mean "complex roots that are not real".  This is an unfortunate abuse of terminology.  But the statement of FTA is not using that abuse of terminology: real roots are included as complex roots.

Comment: "*unless "Complex Root" means something different than "Imaginary Zero"*" $\;-\;$ Yes, the two have different meanings. _Complex Root_ means any complex number, including real numbers. _Imaginary Zero_ usually means a non-zero complex number with real part equal to $0$. Less common usage is to call *imaginary* the non-real complex numbers. In either case, "*a complex number is not necessarily imaginary*", as quoted.

Comment: Thanks all for your help.